# Finding the value of trigonometric function given below.

Tags: trigonometry

if $\alpha$  is a root of $25cos^2 \theta + 5 cos \theta-12 = 0$   ,  $\pi/2<\alpha<\pi$ then the value of $sin 2\alpha$
[My answer is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK4tL.jpg)

Comment: set $$\cos(\theta)=t$$ and solve a quadratic equation

Comment: but I am not getting the correct answer please solve it.

Comment: Please edit your post to show your efforts so far.  Then, we might be able to spot where your calculation is going awry.

Comment: $$35 x 35 =1225= Delta$$

Comment: Looking at your link, you appear to have gotten the quadratic formula wrong. The error is in the computation of the discriminant.

Comment: Side note:  it isn't really necessary to use the quadratic formula.  You can factor $25x^2+5x-12$ directly.

Comment: but the correct answer is -24/25 how did I get it?

Comment: Now that you know where the error in your calculation is, do it again.  Solve the quadratic (correctly).  That will tell you what $\cos (\alpha)$ is.  That is nearly enough.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

find $\cos (\alpha)  (<0)$ by solving quadric .

$$\cos (\alpha)=\frac {-5-\sqrt {1225}}{50}=-4/5$$

and use 
$$\sin (2\alpha)=2\cos (\alpha)\sin (\alpha) $$
$$=2\cos (\alpha)\sqrt {1-\cos^2 (\alpha)} $$

since $\pi/2 <\alpha <\pi $.

You will find $$-\frac {24}{25} $$

Answer (score 0):

we have $$25\cos(\theta)^2+5\cos(\theta)-12=0$$ with $$t=\cos(\theta)$$ we get
$$25t^2+5t-12=0$$
$$t^2+\frac{1}{5}t-\frac{12}{25}=0$$
$$t_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{10}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{100}+\frac{48}{100}}$$
thus $$t_1=-\frac{1}{10}+\frac{7}{10}$$
$$t_2=-\frac{8}{10}$$
can you finish?

Comment: but the correct answer is -24/25

Comment: @SameerSharma yes it is.

Comment: @SameerSharma What do $t_1$ and $t_2$ stand for in this post? Notice the last sentence: this isn't a complete answer, and you're supposed to finish it, to get the desired conclusion.